# Wordpress, Varnish, Nginx + php5-fpm - php5-fpm firing every hit.

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress, varnish

I am hosting a wordpress site on a 512Mb digitalocean VPS. All is good, varnish is getting a perfect hit rate. Logged in users bypass.

The only thing i am noticing is php5-fpm is firing every visit.

How can i track down what is managing to bypass the cache and pass on to the backend.

The system load is drastically better and varnish is amazing for such a small VPS but its my goal to find out why php5-fpm is firing when i dont think it is needed.

thanks

Comment: Dumb question, but what about the access.log?

Answer (score 0):

Two options I know of:

- Turn on access logging for php5-fpm - I'm not 100% sure how, but I've done it with HHVM so it should be possible and quite easy
- Add a header to each location block (if you have the [headers module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#readme) compiled in, [instructions here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx)), then use curl or Firefox with the "Live HTTP Headers" plugin to view requests and responses. The header will tell you what request was serviced by which location block.

```
location (whatever) {
  (php stuff)
  add_header Z_LOCATION "DESCRIBE LOCATION NAME"; add_header URI $uri;
}
```